# Spree 2.1 strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, strong-parameters

Is there a easy way to add a new permitted parameter to controllers in Spree without altering the defaults ?

I'm trying to change the orders_params method in OrdersController.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to override anything, you have to do this in your spree initializer

To add a strong param to products controller...

```
Spree::PermittedAttributes.product_attributes << :new_attribute
```

and so on..

check this file: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/permitted_attributes.rb?source=c

or this blog post: http://blog.crowdint.com/2014/06/24/how-to-add-custom-attributes-in-spree.html

Comment: Nice @Steven, that is even better. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to override this function:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.4/core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/strong_parameters.rb#L28-L32

to include the parameters you want.  The [Spree Logic Customization Guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html) should give you instructions on how to override that method in that class easily.

Comment: Yeah that was the droid I was looking for. Thanks.